# start kafka consumer once event is completed

Tags: apache-kafka, event-handling, spring-kafka

My Spring boot application does two task

1. Initialise cache
2. kafka consumer

Already have a ApplicationEvent for cache initialisation and I want consumer to start listening the messages once cache initialisation is completed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@KafkaListener`, give it an `id` and set `autoStartup` to `false`.

When you are ready, use the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean to start the container.

`registry.getMessageListenerContainer("myId").start()`.

If you are using a listener container bean, set its `autoStartup` to `false` and `start()` it when ready.